# Why is keras way slower than sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, logistic-regression

I'm dealing with a simple logistic regression problem. Each sample contains 7423 features. Totally 4000 training samples and 1000 testing samples. Sklearn takes 0.01s to train the model and achieves 97% accuracy, but Keras (TensorFlow backend) takes 10s to achieve same accuracy after 50 epoches (even one epoch is 20x slower than sklearn). Anyone can shed light on this huge gap?

Samples:

```py
    X_train: matrix of 4000*7423, 0.0 <= value <= 1.0
    y_train: matrix of 4000*1, value = 0.0 or 1.0

    X_test: matrix of 1000*7423, 0.0 <= value <= 1.0
    y_test: matrix of 1000*1, value = 0.0 or 1.0
```

Sklearn code:

```py
    from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    classifier = LogisticRegression()

    **# Finished in 0.01s**
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
    print('test accuracy = %.2f' % accuracy_score(predictions, y_test))

    *[output]: test accuracy = 0.97*
```

Keras code:

```py
    # Using TensorFlow as backend
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    **# Finished in 10s**
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=50, verbose=0)

    result = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('test accuracy = %.2f' % result[1])

    *[output]: test accuracy = 0.97*
```

Comment: Training on CPU or GPU? Try with a batch size = 4000

Answer (score 3):

It might be the optimizer or the loss. You use a non linearity. You also use probably a different batch size under the hood in sklearn.

But the way I see it is that you have a specific task, one of the tool is tailored and made to resolve it, the other is a more complex structure that can resolve it but is not optimized to do so and probably does a lot of things that are not needed for this problem which slows everything down.